# Mule Transform Message

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I am integrating data from Salesforce to another API.  The source has 1 object with related child object.  However target API needs to take form like below.  Each related Salesforce record in child object needs node within subforms. The POST example below is the ultimate desired form for the payload.

I suppose I need to recurse using DataWeave utilizing a For Each with each child record from Salesforce.  But I'm not quite sure where to start with that.

Here is the incoming JSON from Salesforce post topic:

```
{
  "LastModifiedDate": "2016-09-22T14:19:08.000+0000",
  "Engagement__c": "1234",
  "Product_CoC__c": null,
  "Name": "Prod-22880",
  "Year_1_Approved_Production_Hectares__c": 100.0,
  "Year_1_Approved_Production_Volume__c": 1000.0,
  "Product_Variety__c": null,
  "CreatedById": "1234",
  "Year_2_Estimated_Production_Volume__c": 1001.0,
  "Product__c": "1234",
  "Engagement_Decision_Date__c": null,
  "Year_1_Harvest_Period__c": "2016",
  "CPH_Number__c": null,
  "Product_Type__c": null,
  "Certificate_Product__c": "1234",
  "IsDeleted": false,
  "Crop_Yield__c": 10.0,
  "Year_2_Estimated_Production_Hectares__c": 100.0,
  "Valid_Period_End_Date__c": null,
  "Intercrop__c": false,
  "SystemModstamp": "2016-09-22T14:19:08.000+0000",
  "Year_2_Harvest_Period__c": null,
  "Crop_Production_Unit__c": "kg",
  "Certificate__c": "1234",
  "Year__c": 1.0,
  "Harvest_Frequency__c": "Single",
  "CreatedDate": "2016-07-28T15:44:18.000+0000",
  "Valid_Period_Start_Date__c": null,
  "Id": "1234",
  "LastModifiedById": "1234",
  "RA_Id__c": null
}
```

Here is the Transform Message I have for the child object:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    acv_crop3:flowVars.ChainpointCropID default "",
    acv_cph3:payload.Name default "",
    acv_harvest_period2:payload.Year_1_Harvest_Period__c default "",
    acv_frequency2:flowVars.frequency default "",
    acv_aq2:payload.Year_1_Approved_Production_Volume__c default "",
    acv_cph4:payload.Year_1_Approved_Production_Hectares__c default "",
    acv_yield2:payload.Crop_Yield__c default "",
    acv_start_date2:payload.Valid_Period_Start_Date__c default "",
    acv_end_date2:payload.Valid_Period_End_Date__c default "",
    acv_uom2:flowVars.uom default ""
}
```

Here is an example of a desired POST payload:

```
{
  "ownerId": 24695,
  "Q_CERT_SFGUID": "a00G000000WR3xxxxx",
  "Q_CERT": "467",
  "Q_CERTCROP2": [
    "1199"
  ],
  "textId": "auto",
  "resultDate": null,
  "authorId": null,
  "Q_CERTNO": "RA-G-",
  "Q_CERTHL": 24695,
  "Q_CERTCB": 43986,
  "Q_CERTST": "NO_STATUS",
  "Q_CERTSUB": "",
  "Q_CERTSTDATE": "2016-06-30",
  "Q_CERT_expiration_date": "2019-06-29",
  "Q_CERTENDATE": "",
  "Q_CERT_redate": "2016-06-30",
  "Q_CERT_CHA": "8.0",
  "Q_CERT_TPH": "8.0",
  "Q_CERT_CONTACT_EMAIL": "m@gmail.com",
  "Q_CERT_CONTACT_NAME": 1300,
  "subforms": [
    {
      "textId": "acv2",
      "rows": [
        {
          "acv_crop3": "1199",
          "acv_cph3": "Prod-22880",
          "acv_harvest_period2": "2016",
          "acv_frequency2": 668,
          "acv_aq2": 1000,
          "acv_cph4": 100,
          "acv_yield2": 10,
          "acv_start_date2": "2099-12-31",
          "acv_end_date2": "2099-12-31",
          "acv_uom2": 557
        },
        {
          "acv_crop3": "1100",
          "acv_cph3": "Prod-22881",
          "acv_harvest_period2": "2017",
          "acv_frequency2": 668,
          "acv_aq2": 1000,
          "acv_cph4": 100,
          "acv_yield2": 1000,
          "acv_start_date2": "2017-12-31",
          "acv_end_date2": "2018-12-31",
          "acv_uom2": 557
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the flow I have so far with the Transform message...

```
    <flow name="prepareEP">
        <set-variable variableName="API_Path" value="v0/forms/FR_CERT" doc:name="engagementProduct API_URL"/>
        <set-variable variableName="entityType" value="engagementProduct" doc:name="set Entity"/>
        <component class="com.ww.mule.reporting.et.ObjectStoreController" doc:name="load countryDiccionary"/>
        <set-variable variableName="originalPayloadEP" value="#[payload]" doc:name="original payload"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <set-variable variableName="originalPayloadEPMap" value="#[payload]" doc:name="original payload map"/>
        <logger message="#['About to query certificate ' + flowVars.originalPayloadEPMap.Certificate__c + ' with engagement product Id ' + flowVars.originalPayloadEPMap.Id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication"  doc:name="Get Engagement Products By Cert" query="dsql:SELECT Id,Name,Year_1_Harvest_Period__c,Harvest_Frequency__c,Year_1_Approved_Production_Volume__c,Year_1_Approved_Production_Hectares__c,Crop_Yield__c,Valid_Period_Start_Date__c,Valid_Period_End_Date__c FROM Engagement_Product__c WHERE Certificate__c = '#[flowVars.originalPayloadEPMap.Certificate__c]'"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="CountryStoreObjectStore" key="#[payload.Cert_Country__c == empty?'UNKNOWN_COUNTRY':payload.Cert_Country__c]" targetProperty="countryISO" doc:name="ObjectStore" defaultValue-ref="#['XX']"/>
            <set-payload value="#[flowVars.originalPayloadEP]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
            <set-variable variableName="frequency" value="#[originalPayloadEPMap.Harvest_Frequency__c == 'Single' ? 668 : originalPayloadEPMap.Harvest_Frequency__c == 'Multiple' ? 669 : originalPayloadEPMap.Harvest_Frequency__c == 'Permanent/Continuous' ? 667 : originalPayloadEPMap.Harvest_Frequency__c == 'Occasional' ? 1910 : null]" doc:name="Set Harvest Frequency Variable"/>
            <set-variable variableName="uom" value="#[originalPayloadEPMap.Crop_Production_Unit__c == 'kg' ? 557 : originalPayloadEPMap.Crop_Production_Unit__c == 'Liters' ? 596 : originalPayloadEPMap.Crop_Production_Unit__c == 'Number of Stems' ? 1802 : originalPayloadEPMap.Crop_Production_Unit__c == 'mts2' ? 556 : null]" doc:name="Set UOM Variable"/>
            <!--
            <set-payload   doc:name="Set Payload"/>
            --> 
            <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    acv_crop3:flowVars.ChainpointCropID default "",
    acv_cph3:payload.Name default "",
    acv_harvest_period2:payload.Year_1_Harvest_Period__c default "",
    acv_frequency2:flowVars.frequency default "",
    acv_aq2:payload.Year_1_Approved_Production_Volume__c default "",
    acv_cph4:payload.Year_1_Approved_Production_Hectares__c default "",
    acv_yield2:payload.Crop_Yield__c default "",
    acv_start_date2:payload.Valid_Period_Start_Date__c default "",
    acv_end_date2:payload.Valid_Period_End_Date__c default "",
    acv_uom2:flowVars.uom default ""
}]]>
                </dw:set-payload>
            </dw:transform-message>
            <object-to-string-transformer mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Object to String"/>
            <set-variable variableName="acv2_info" value="#[flowVars.acv2_info == null ? payload : flowVars.acv2_info + ',' + payload]" doc:name="acv2_info"/>
            <logger message="#['acv2_info = ' + flowVars.acv2_info]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <set-variable variableName="transformedPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="save payload"/>
            <logger message="#['transformedPayload = ' + flowVars.transformedPayload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Print transformedPayload"/>
        </foreach>
        <flow-ref name="sendAuthenticatedChainPointRequest" doc:name="sendAuthenticatedChainPointRequest"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Please post your input data

Comment: Thanks for your attention Anil!  I've put the incoming JSON above in the question.

Comment: What is your question? Your output requires `"ownerId": 24695` but I don't see a field related to that? Where is that coming from? Are you trying to build up only the `rows` child element? I need more information from you.

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I am trying to build up only the rows child element.  I have a Transform message for the first part of the payload.  Each related Salesforce record (represented in the first payload above) is a child object that I need within the subforms node in the desired POST payload.  Since my original post I have a For Each that properly recurses but still having trouble building the flow variable.  I will post the flow here.